# Check on Linux certain port is occupied

Tags: linux-networking, port

I'm writing a script that will spin up server that want to use certain port number. In some occasions this port is occupied. I want to know how to check it in bash so I can react in proper way.

How can I check on linux certain port is occupied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use netcat to check if port is listening something:

```
PORT_STATUS=$(nc -v <host> -z <port number> 2>&1 | grep open | wc -l )
if [[ "$PORT_STATUS" = "1" ]];then
    echo Port is occupied
fi
```

This of course only works if there isn't firewall blocking netcat. But if you run it locally on the server then at least there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: I don't know is this because of flavor and/or version number but in my case nc gives me message "Connection to localhost 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!" so I suggest to use 'succeeded' instead of 'open' in grep. But except this everything is great!

Answer (score 0):

If you have in mind TCP port, you can check with netstat, something like this might work:

```
 netstat -ntp |  grep -v '::' | awk  '{print $4}'  | grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq
```

Of course this is not atomic, so it possible that some port will taken after check operation but before your service will start.